# I can't passing variable to PHP from JavaScript and jQuery load the response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want passing 2 parameters to PHP page via AJAX and load the response, but this code is not working.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(".show_category").click(function(){
    var category_id = $(this).attr('data-category');
    $.ajax({
        url: "conx.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            action: "sort_category",
            category_id: category_id
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#con").load("conx.php");
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    echo "1".$_POST["action"]."<br/>";
?>
```

Comment: On success try : $("#con").html (data);

Answer (score 0):

You issue is here:

```
    success: function(data) {
        $("#con").load("conx.php");
    }
```

At this point, you have already posted the data and received the HTML response. There is no need to make another HTTML request by calling `.load`, and doing so will mean requesting it again without the POST data, so it will not have the intended effect. Just use the HTML you already have in the `data` argument.

```
    success: function(data) {
        $("#con").html(data);
    }
```

---

On a side note, this PHP code is a [reflected XSS vulnerability](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65142/what-is-reflected-xss):

```
<?php
    echo "1".$_POST["action"]."<br/>";
?>
```

Comment: Alexander O'Mara : Thank you for help. I will try to write it again .